# Can I use the 'react-redux' 'connect' HOC to provide custom selectors to 'generic' React components through mapStateToProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, code-reuse

I'm trying to create re-usable React components for a large React project my team is working on.  For instance, I have a panel which consists of two sub-components, each of which consists of further sub-components.

The best place for me to connect to the Redux store is at the top level and pass props down to the sub and sub-sub components (I know this defeats somewhat the purpose of Redux, but otherwise the entire thing grows too complicated).

My problem was how to provide different selectors to each of the 'instances' of this generic top level component so that they would have different data fed to them.  The solution I came up with was to wrap each 'instance' in another component which would only really consist of wrapping the 'generic' component in the HOC 'connect' function and passing custom selectors through `mapStateToProps`.

That is, I'd have the 'generic component

```
// GenericPanelComponent.js
class GenericPanelComponent extends React.Component {
...
// component code
}
export default GenericPanelComponent
```

then each 'instance' would provide distinct data through 'connect'

```
// SpecificInstance1.js 
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import GenericPanelComponent from './GenericPanelComponent';


class SpecificInstance1 extends React.component {
// no code
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ specificInstanceData: specificInstance1Selector(state) });
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(GenericPanelComponent);
```

and

```
 // SpecificInstance2.js 
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import GenericPanelComponent from './GenericPanelComponent';

 // SpecificInstance2.js 
    class SpecificInstance2 extends React.component {
    // no code
    }
    const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ specificInstanceData: specificInstance2Selector(state) });
    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(GenericPanelComponent);
```

Is there anything conceptually or architecturally wrong with this approach?  If so, how does one feed custom Redux selectors and data to re-usable React components? Thanks for any insights!

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with this approach, HOC like connect are designed to have this kind of benefit.

To use this effectively you'd have to work out what props your GenericPanelComponent would need and supply them using the connect function. The only thing I would point out in your current implementation is that the GenericPanelComponent shouldn't need to know which type of Panel it is, so it shouldn't have different props as you've done it

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ specificInstance1Data: specificInstance1Selector(state) });
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ specificInstance2Data: specificInstance2Selector(state) });
```

And instead the data should come through on one prop

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ specificInstanceData: specificInstance1Selector(state) });
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ specificInstanceData: specificInstance2Selector(state) });
```

Comment: Thanks -- you're absolutely right!  I'll correct it in the code above...

Comment: do I even need to have the blank code in the 'instance' component?  Could I just export the connected generic component from the 'instance' component?     `const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ specificInstanceData: specificInstance2Selector(state) });
    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(GenericPanelComponent);`

Comment: Yes, there is no need for the instance component